# Return custom response in an asp.NET rest endpoint for bad calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a rest api with an endpoint that looks like this:

```
[Route("create")]
[HttpPost]
public object CreateStuff ([FromBody] MyParams args)
{
    //...
}
```

For simplicity's sake, let's say that MyParams is an object with a single field of type enum:

```
public Enum SomeType {
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
}

public MyParams {
    SomeType Test {get; set;}
}
```

You can call this with a body like this:

```
{
    "SomeType": "Two"
}
```

And it will work fine. However, if you call this with a value that doesn't make sense, such as `"SomeType": "Invented value"`, it will return a 400 Bad Request response with a body like this:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-c44995191a9c99604f9944c2b1542245-caa753444c07f89e-00",
    "errors": {
        "args": [
            "The args field is required."
        ],
        "$.canalEntrada": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[...]. Path: $.SomeType| LineNumber: 7 | BytePositionInLine: 28."
        ]
    }
}
```

Can I change this body so it is anything I want?

Comment: I would advise against that. This is an [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) Problem Details response that can be broadly understood.

Comment: That's what I thought. But my boss doesn't like the default error body response. He says it looks unprofessional because it's not ours and that I have to change it for a custom one.

Comment: The message is coming from the model binder, so you could instead accept it as `string`, do the parsing in the controller, and provide your own message at that point. Or write your own model binder for that type.

Comment: It's important to separate the message from the structure. Don't lose the well-defined structure just because you want to change the message. It's a *baby / bath water* situation.

Comment: It's like passing a string value to an Int property! BTW you could use a top-level middleware to catch such these errors.

Answer (score 0):

**Use controller modelState object**

```cs
[Route("create")]
[HttpPost]
public object CreateStuff ([FromBody] MyParams args)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return BadRequest(new{ status = false, message = "this bad data" });
    }
}
```

**Update**

*We must disable auto BadRequestError Response for `WebApi` by:*

```cs
services.AddControllers().ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true);
```

[Disable automatic 400 response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#disable-automatic-400-response)

[Handle errors in ASP.NET Core web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: That won't help. The model binder is returning the error before the action method is called.

Comment: @madreflection by disabling `services.AddControllers() .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true);` should solve this.  from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#automatic-http-400-responses

Comment: You didn't say that in your answer. It's incomplete.

Comment: It's a shotgun approach on its own, though, and has broad-reaching effects.

Comment: This is the solution I'll go with. I'm not a fan of replacing something that already works with my own, shittier version - but if that's what my boss wants, so be it. I'll let him choose between the previous, perfectly fine (imo) default error and the new "oopsie woopsie something went wrong" custom one.

Comment: @Kaisadilla believe me, catch what's useful while the hand can handle. The more we practice the more we understand. I recommend `middleware` but this solution is the step to that stage. See more for [WebApi error handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-7.0)